# How can I find specific values inside a multidimensional array?

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

I'm making a game that's a lot like checkers, to create the board I used a multidimensional array. I populate the array with 0's on every empty space and then the one set of chips is represented by 1's and the other is represented by 2's. Is there any way in which I can get a list of what spaces are being occupied by each set of chips? This is my gameboard:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2]]

print "\n".join(" ".join(str(el) for el in row) for row in matrix)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While list-comprehensions are often a nice way to build a single list, you'll have to go through the entire matrix multiple times to find the positions of every possible chip value. Alternatively, you could create lists of which spaces are occupied by each kind of chip in a single pass through the matrix by doing something like the following:

```
matrix = [[1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
          [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2],
          [0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2], [0,0,0,0,0,2,2,2,2,2]]

positions = {}
for y in xrange(len(matrix)):
    for x in xrange(len(matrix)):
        positions.setdefault(matrix[y][x], []).append((y, x))

# show the all positions of each chip value
for chip in sorted(positions):
    print('{}: {}'.format(chip, positions[chip]))
```

Output:

```
0: [(0, 5), (0, 6), (0, 7), (0, 8), (0, 9), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (1, 7), (1, 8), (1, 9), (2, 3), (2, 4), (2, 5), (2, 6), (2, 7), (2, 8), (2, 9), (3, 2), (3, 3), (3, 4), (3, 5), (3, 6), (3, 7), (3, 8), (3, 9), (4, 1), (4, 2), (4, 3), (4, 4), (4, 5), (4, 6), (4, 7), (4, 8), (4, 9), (5, 0), (5, 1), (5, 2), (5, 3), (5, 4), (5, 5), (5, 6), (5, 7), (5, 8), (6, 0), (6, 1), (6, 2), (6, 3), (6, 4), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (7, 0), (7, 1), (7, 2), (7, 3), (7, 4), (7, 5), (7, 6), (8, 0), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (8, 4), (8, 5), (9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), (9, 3), (9, 4)]
1: [(0, 0), (0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 0), (3, 1), (4, 0)]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
2: [(5, 9), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use list comprehension with condition, following code returns all the spaces occupied by 2:

```
[(y, x) for y in xrange(len(matrix)) for x in xrange(len(matrix[y])) if matrix[y][x] == 2]
```

Output:

```
[(5, 9), (6, 8), (6, 9), (7, 7), (7, 8), (7, 9), (8, 6), (8, 7), (8, 8), (8, 9), (9, 5), (9, 6), (9, 7), (9, 8), (9, 9)]
```

Comment: Hey thanks that's very useful. May I ask you one more question if you don't mind? The reason why I want a list of the locations of the chips is to input them into another function that finds all the possible plays you can make with said chip. My functions accepts two parameters, the x coordinate and the y coordinate of which chip's moves you want to find. The reason why I wanted the locations of the chips inside the list is so I could use a loop to iterate through all the positions and find all the possible moves for all the chips. Is there any to do this?

Comment: @SirAskALot If you simply want to find possible moves for one set of chips you could do `[find_plays(y, x) for y in ...]` instead of just returning the coordinate. For better answer I'd need to know the return value of `find_plays` and how you'd want to store the result.

Comment: The value that my function returns is a list of the possible coordinates that you can move to. Within my function I have defined an empty list and it appends every possible move. The game is kind of like checkers, only you can move in all directions so I check all the adjacent coordinates and only store the coordinates that have 0 as its value. However I do have another function for hopping, if the space right next to you is full but the space after that space is empty you can hop on top of the chip. The function for hopping works in the same was as the function for basic move.